# Unable to start Activemq using Java

Tags: java, activemq-classic, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to start   *activemq* on my Ubuntu machine. I am trying to start the service using *Java*. The below is my code:

```
Runtime rt=  Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /home/varkala/Srinivas /Prime360/softwares/apache-activemq-5.5.1/bin;./activemq start"});
```

I also tried to run the ***run.jar***  in the bin folder. But it did not work

```
rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /home/varkala/Srinivas /Prime360/softwares/apache-activemq-5.5.1/bin;java -jar run.jar start"});
```

These are the error logs:

```
  /bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /home/varkala/Srinivas
    Can't open startup.sh
```

But when I open the terminal manually and execute the command , activemq starts. Is there something wrong with my code?

Update: Strangely, I tried to execute the cd command with another directory: /home/Varkala/Desktop .. the command is working fine.But for the above mentioned directory , I am getting error

Comment: I'm afraid "it doesn't work" is not enough for us to try and determine a cause. Are there any errors or logging output you could share?

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku provided the error logs

Comment: Try the startup script instead of running the jar directly https://activemq.apache.org/unix-shell-script

Comment: Wait, is the home directory /home/Varkala or /home/varkala/Srinivas (2 levels deep)?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you're using a Java program to call a shell script to start a Java program? Why not simply run the broker embedded from your Java program?

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku it is /home/varkala

Comment: Then why do you attempt to cd into /home/varkala/Srinivas?

Comment: Sorry for the late response . The location of the file I am trying to cd  into is  /home/varkala/Srinivas /Prime360/softwares/apache-activemq-5.5.1/bin

Answer (score 0):

This  may not be technically correct answer. Whenever I tried to copy the full path , I noticed there is a ***space***   between two folders of my path ***Srinivas*** and ***Prime360*** .You can observe it in the first line of code in my question.For files in other locations like *Desktop* , I did not see that space while copying and pasting the full path in my program. All I did was , I renamed my folder from ***Srinivas*** to ***srinivas*** and surprisingly, it worked . I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS